# Add Item with Bootsrap Modal in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a project that similar to the shopping cart.

But, user will need to add  item on the Child Window(Bootstrap Modal) then after submit then will auto show the item on the Parent Window **without refresh page.**

I have met a problem when submit the items , the items will save as session then retrieve on the Parent window.

I tried to var_dump the session, it can show the array, but I have no idea to retrieve the session data on the Parent Window.

Controller:

```
    public function index(){
        $data['session'] = is_array($this->session->userdata('item'))?array_values(unserialize($this->session->userdata('item'))) : array();
        $data['product'] = $this->test->GetProduct();
        $data['category'] = $this->test->GetCategory();
        $this->load->view('import/test',$data);
    }

    public function AddCart(){
        $product = $this->input->post('product_type');
        $category = $this->input->post('category_code');
        $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
        $quality = $this->input->post('quality');
        $gold_rate = $this->input->post('gold_rate');
        $weight = $this->input->post('weight');
        $item_remarks = $this->input->post('item_remarks');
        $assessed_value = $this->input->post('assessed_value');
        $pledge_amt = $this->input->post('pledge_amt');

        $Pledge_Item = array(
                                'Product' => $product,
                                'Category' => $category,
                                'Qty' => $qty,
                                'Quality' => $quality,
                                'Gold_Rate' => $gold_rate,
                                'Weight' => $weight,
                                'Item_Remarks' => $item_remarks,
                                'Assessed_Value' => $assessed_value,
                                'Pledge_Amt' => $pledge_amt
                             );
        //$this->session->set_userdata('item',$Pledge_Item);
        //$Session   = $this->session->userdata('item');
        //var_dump($Session); 
        if(!$this->session->has_userdata('item')) {
            $item = array($Pledge_Item);
            $this->session->set_userdata('item', serialize($item));
        } else {
            //$index = $this->exists($product);
            $item = array_values(unserialize($this->session->userdata('item')));
            array_push($item, $Pledge_Item);
            $this->session->set_userdata('item', serialize($item));

        }
        //var_dump($item);
        redirect('Test/index');
    }
```

View(Parent Window)

```
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="result">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Product Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Category</th>
                    <th scope="col">Qty</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quality</th>
                    <th scope="col">Gold Rate</th>
                    <th scope="col">Weight</th>
                    <th scope="col">Item Remarks</th>
                    <th scope="col">Assessed Value</th>
                    <th scope="col">Pledge Amount</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($session as $row){?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Product'];?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

View(Child Window-Bootstrap Model)

```
                   <div class="modal-body">
                        <?php echo form_open("Test/AddCart"); ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php
                                    $options = array(
                                                     '' => '~Select Product~'
                                                     );
                                    foreach ($product as $prod){
                                        $options[$prod->product_id] = $prod->product_type;
                                    }

                                    $select = array(
                                                    'name' => 'product_type[]',
                                                    'id'    => 'product_type',
                                                    'class' => 'form-control form-pledge-item',
                                                    'required' => 'required'
                                                    );
                                    echo form_dropdown('product_type[]', $options,set_value('product_type'),$select);
                                ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php
                                    $options = array(
                                                     '' => '~Select Category~'
                                                     );
                                    foreach ($category as $categ){
                                        $options[$categ->category_id] = $categ->category_code;
                                    }

                                    $select = array(
                                                    'name' => 'category_code[]',
                                                    'id'    => 'category_code',
                                                    'class' => 'form-control form-pledge-item',
                                                    'required' => 'required'
                                                    );
                                    echo form_dropdown('category_code[]', $options,set_value('category_code'),$select);
                                ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="qty[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Quantity" min="0" required/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="quality[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Quality"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="gold_rate[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Gold Rate/gm" min="0" step="any"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="weight[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Weight" min="0" step="any"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="item_remarks[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Item Remarks"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="assessed_value[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Assessed Value" min="0" step="any"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="pledge_amt[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Pledge Amount" min="0" step="any"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <!--<button value="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-12" id="add_row">Add</button>-->
                            <button name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info col-md-12"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Item</button>
                            <!--<a class="btn btn-info col-md-12" href="<?php echo base_url() .'index.php/Test/AddCart/'; ?>">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</a>-->
                            <br>
                        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                    </div>
```

Comment: you should use ajax and you can add item if you want i will show you how to do it

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov Can you show me? Thanks much.

Comment: when form submitted should it save to database

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov No, when user click button on child window, the item will show as table row in parent window, after user click button on parent window, then only will insert into database

Comment: ok i got it jut wait few minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="javascript:void(0)" id="addcard">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php
                                    $options = array(
                                                     '' => '~Select Product~'
                                                     );
                                    foreach ($product as $prod){
                                        $options[$prod->product_id] = $prod->product_type;
                                    }

                                    $select = array(
                                                    'name' => 'product_type[]',
                                                    'id'    => 'product_type',
                                                    'class' => 'form-control form-pledge-item',
                                                    'required' => 'required'
                                                    );
                                    echo form_dropdown('product_type[]', $options,set_value('product_type'),$select);
                                ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php
                                    $options = array(
                                                     '' => '~Select Category~'
                                                     );
                                    foreach ($category as $categ){
                                        $options[$categ->category_id] = $categ->category_code;
                                    }

                                    $select = array(
                                                    'name' => 'category_code[]',
                                                    'id'    => 'category_code',
                                                    'class' => 'form-control form-pledge-item',
                                                    'required' => 'required'
                                                    );
                                    echo form_dropdown('category_code[]', $options,set_value('category_code'),$select);
                                ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="qty[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Quantity" min="0" required/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="quality[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Quality"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="gold_rate[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Gold Rate/gm" min="0" step="any"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="weight[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Weight" min="0" step="any"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="item_remarks[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Item Remarks"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="assessed_value[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Assessed Value" min="0" step="any"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="pledge_amt[]" class="form-control form-pledge-item" placeholder="Pledge Amount" min="0" step="any"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><br>
                            <!--<button value="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-12" id="add_row">Add</button>-->
                            <button name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info col-md-12"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Item</button>
                            <!--<a class="btn btn-info col-md-12" href="<?php echo base_url() .'index.php/Test/AddCart/'; ?>">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</a>-->
                            <br>
                        </form>
                    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addcaard").on('submit', function(){
            var url='Test/AddCart';
            var formArray=$(this).serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data:formArray,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#result").children("tbody").append(data);
                },
                error: function(err){
                     console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

this is controller

public function

```
AddCart(){
    $product = $this->input->post('product_type');
    $category = $this->input->post('category_code');
    $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
    $quality = $this->input->post('quality');
    $gold_rate = $this->input->post('gold_rate');
    $weight = $this->input->post('weight');
    $item_remarks = $this->input->post('item_remarks');
    $assessed_value = $this->input->post('assessed_value');
    $pledge_amt = $this->input->post('pledge_amt');
    $data = "<tr><td>".$product."</td><td>".$category."</td><td>".$qty."</td><td>".$quality."</td><td>".$gold_rate."</td><td>".$weight."</td><td>".$item_remarks."</td><td>".$assessed_value."</td><td>".$pledge_amt."</td></tr>";
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: by the way don't forget to close modal when form submit